# Receiving submodel or tool name as input using QGIS or ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I would like the user to select the tool (or submodel) to be used from among a list of names. 
Can I do this in QGIS or ArcGIS ModelBuilder without having to write a python script?

Actually, what I would like is the user to input in a table as below (like in the "union" tool in ArcGIS)

First column: a raster layer. Second column: the submodel or tool selected from a drop down list. Then a couple of columns for inputting values to be passed on to parameters in the selected submodel. I would also like the user to be able to add as many rows (i.e. rasters) as necessary.

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question.